# how model use for display two tables in a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to display elements of two tables in a view but I don't know how.

In my view i Have @model IEnumerable which point to 'Tmembre' class of the model and corresponding of the table 'Tmembre' in database.
I can display elements of this table in my view, OK.

but I also want to display elements of another table in the this view and I can't put other @model déclaration in the view.

I try to create a class in the model for two table and put the sql in the model but i think it s not in the model i have to request DB.

```
public class myviewmodel
{
    public Tmembre tmembre { get; set; }
    public List<Tmembre> GetlstMembre { // SQL }

    public TAssociation tassociation { get; set; }
    public List<TAssociation> GetlstAssociation { // SQL  }
}
```

Comment: Removed the [tag:asp-classic] tag.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller you can create a new instance of the above ViewModel and fill the members with data from your database.

Once done you should return this ViewModel to your View;

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   MyViewModel myViewModel = new MyViewModel();
   myViewModel.lstmembre = ....;
   myViewModel.1stassociation = ...;

   return View(myViewModel);    
}
```

In your view you can now specify the @model as your view model

```
@model myproject.web.models.MyViewModel
```

Now all members of this model should be available for you to access from your view

```
Model.1stmembre
Model.1stassociation
Model.tmembre
etc..
```

Comment: thanks uk2k05, I need all elements of Association table and also one element of Membre table. I will use `dbcontext.table.tolist()` for Association table and use a resquest for Membre table. thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK
            ViewBag.Message = "Liste des membres";

```
        //Chercher les informations du membre connecté
        //Tmembre Membre = db.TmembresansEDMdb.Find(10);
        //TAssociation association = db.dbTassociation.Find(Membre.Idassociation);

        //ViewData.Model = (from a in db.TmembresansEDMdb
        //                  where a.Idassociation == Membre.Idassociation
         //                 select a );


        myviewmodel mymodel = new myviewmodel();
        Tmembre Membre = db.TmembresansEDMdb.Find(1);

        mymodel.lstassociation = db.dbTassociation.ToList();
        ViewData["Idassociation"] = Membre.Idassociation;
        mymodel.lstmembre= (from a in db.TmembresansEDMdb
                          where a.Idassociation == Membre.Idassociation
                          select a ).ToList();
        return View(mymodel);
```

In View

```
                @foreach (var item in Model.lstassociation)
                {
                    if (item.Nomassociation == @ViewData["Idassociation"])
                    {
                        <option selected>@item.Nomassociation</option>
                    } else {
                        <option>@item.Nomassociation</option>                            
                    }
                }

    @foreach (var item in Model.lstmembre) {
        <div class="divmembre">
            <div class="dphoto"><img src="~/Content/@item.SRCImage"/></div>
            <div class="containerdetail">
                <div class="ddetail">
                    <div class="ddetaild nom">@item.Nommembre</div>
                    <div class="ddetaild prenom">@item.Prenommembre</div>
                    <div class="ddetaild mail">@item.Mailmembre</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

All elements of lstmembre are displayed but I want to select in a list the element of table Association corresponding with Idassociation in the view data. I have message : no entry point in 
if (item.Nomassociation == ViewData["Idassociation"])

but if I use @ViewData["Idassociation"] in HTML Tag and not in a loop it s ok, the value is displayed. I think it s just a syntax error. tks

Comment: OK thanks I use :`var assocsel = ViewData["Idassociation"];
if (item.Idassociation.ToString() == assocsel.ToString())
{
<option selected>@item.Nomassociation</option>
} else {
<option>@item.Nomassociation</option>                            
}`